# Sharepoint/Office365 groups. Security group Vs Distribution list/goup

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, ms-office

I create a Group on Office365 Admin site. It is a Security Group (by default as there is no other option) This Group doesn't have an Email associated to it.
Now I create a Distribution list(Exchange admin center) and when I refresh Office365 admin site page, this group starts showing with an Email address bound to it.

Now my question has several parts.

1) Is there a diff between Security Group created from office365 admin site and Exchange admin center?

2) Why is that Office365 doesn't ask for an email when I create a Group there? But when I create a security group on Exchange admin center, it asks me that!

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I believe the groups under O365 Admin center are Azure AD groups.  You can use them for audience targeting and to assign permissions in SharePoint.

Exchange distribution lists are merely mailing lists.  They are used only in Exchange; they cannot be used to assign permissions in SharePoint.  Given the purpose of distribution groups, an email is necessary.

Comment: Can you please tell me the difference between a Security Group created on Office365 Admin center and a Security group created on Exchange admin center?

Comment: According to O365 help, mail-enabled security groups are used to distribute messages and assigning access to AD resources.  Not entirely sure what that entails, as it's an Exchange item-not something I'm experienced in administrating.